# Adding on Cascade Delete to existing foreign key

Tags: mysql

I have got a foreign key in  one of my tables and wanted to add ON DELETE CASCADE could anyone  advise me on how to do it please :) ? thank you

Comment: @blackpanther i really enjoyed your essay thank you! btw i'm a woman so not planning manning up any time soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See example :**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl1(
      id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      name INT
    )

    CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
      id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
      tbl1_id INT REFERENCES tbl1(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
    )
```

**To add to an existing table :**

```
ALTER TABLE tbl2
   ADD CONSTRAINT tbl1_id_fk
   FOREIGN KEY (tbl1_id)
   REFERENCES tbl1(id)
   ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

If using InnoDB make sure you have FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS parameter set to 1
Verify this with the output from `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'foreign_key_checks' (1=ON, 0=OFF)`

Comment: thanks for your reply. my problem is that the table is already built and i just forgot to add at the end ON DELETE CASCADE. i was wondering if there is a way to edit the table and add it after it's been built.

Comment: Added some new stuff !

Comment: no problem ! Up_One for me if my answer was correct !

Comment: it was correct thank you but i cant vote yet (sorry)